# In CSS, how can I make grid rows be as high as their contents, if there's an adjacent item spanning multiple rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a container with a bunch children that I want to layout like this using CSS:

[image: a screenshot with the desired results]

(I cannot control the HTML, and the contents of the children may vary in size to some extent. This is a minimal example; in actuality, the layout might be more complex.)

I am trying to use CSS grids, as the language of `grid-template` seems to be conveying my idea most clearly. However, I've ran into an issue; in the screenshot, you can see that items `k` and `n` are as high as their contents, and items `l` and `o` take the remaining space. I don't know how to express this with CSS.

If there's only one item that should span the remaining space, I seem to be able to use `min-content` (or `auto`) and `1fr`.

```css
container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "j k" min-content
    "j l" 1fr;
}

j { grid-area: j; }
k { grid-area: k; }
l { grid-area: l; }

container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <j>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br></j>
  <k>k</k>
  <l>l<br>l</l>
</container>
```

However, this trick doesn't work when I have more items that should take the remaining space. Rows that are `1fr` high seem to be trying to take equal amount of vertical space:

```css
container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "j k" min-content
    "j l" 1fr
    "m n" min-content
    "m o" 1fr;
}

j { grid-area: j; }
k { grid-area: k; }
l { grid-area: l; }
m { grid-area: m; }
n { grid-area: n; }
o { grid-area: o; }

container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <j>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br></j>
  <k>k</k>
  <l>l<br>l</l>
  <m>m<br>m<br>m<br>m<br></m>
  <n>n</n>
  <o>o</o>
</container>
```

For the record, if not specifying any values for row heights, it seems that the engine is trying to make the free space in the rows equal height.

```css
container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "j k"
    "j l"
    "m n"
    "m o";
}

j { grid-area: j; }
k { grid-area: k; }
l { grid-area: l; }
m { grid-area: m; }
n { grid-area: n; }
o { grid-area: o; }

container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <j>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br></j>
  <k>k</k>
  <l>l<br>l</l>
  <m>m<br>m<br>m<br>m<br></m>
  <n>n</n>
  <o>o</o>
</container>
```

It is also possible to set the height of `k` and `n` rows to a fixed value. However, in my case the contents of items is slightly variable and I can't use this trick.

```css
container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "j k" 1em
    "j l" 
    "m n" 1em
    "m o";
}

j { grid-area: j; }
k { grid-area: k; }
l { grid-area: l; }
m { grid-area: m; }
n { grid-area: n; }
o { grid-area: o; }

container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <j>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br></j>
  <k>k</k>
  <l>l<br>l</l>
  <m>m<br>m<br>m<br>m<br></m>
  <n>n</n>
  <o>o</o>
</container>
```

So the question is, how can I achieve the layout like in the screenshot above?

Answer (score 1):

This `grid-auto-rows` combination seems to do what you need:

```css
body {
  /* for firefox */
  display: grid;
}

container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "j k"
    "j l"
    "m n"
    "m o"
  ;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content minmax(auto, 100%); /*  */
}

j { grid-area: j; }
k { grid-area: k; }
l { grid-area: l; }
m { grid-area: m; }
n { grid-area: n; }
o { grid-area: o; }

container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <j>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j</j>
  <k>k</k>
  <l>l<br>l</l>
  <m>m<br>m<br>m<br>m</m>
  <n>n</n>
  <o>o</o>
</container>
```

Comment: Thank you, `minmax(min-content, 100%)` seems to do the trick! While this works, I don't quite get *why* it works. I tried all sorts of combinations of values before. I would appreciate it if you explained how you came up with the solution, or if you have good articles about this it would be cool as well.

Comment: Oh, and by the way this doesn't quite work well in Firefox 

Comment:  Yes you're right... It looks like firefox wants an explicitly specified `height` for the `container` so that `minmax(auto, 100%)` works. To work around this, you can set `display: grid;` on the parent element. In our case, it is the `body`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but `position: absolute` can fix this but you need to be sure the `j` an `m` are always bigger than the right elements

```css
container {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template:
    "j k"
    "j l" 
    "m n"
    "m o";
}

j { grid-area: j; }
k { grid-area: k; }
l { grid-area: l; }
m { grid-area: m; }
n { grid-area: n; }
o { grid-area: o; }

l,o {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <j>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br></j>
  <k>k</k>
  <l>l<br>l</l>
  <m>m<br>m<br>m<br>m<br></m>
  <n>n</n>
  <o>o</o>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is a simplification of the actual code, I don't know if this answer is ok for you.

One way to handle this is to split the grid in 2.

```css
container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:   "j k"     "j l" ;
  grid-template-columns: 50%;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
}

j { grid-area: j; }
k { grid-area: k; }
l { grid-area: l; }
m { grid-area: j; }
n { grid-area: k; }
o { grid-area: l; }

container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <j>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br>j<br></j>
  <k>k</k>
  <l>l<br>l</l>
 </container>
 <container>
  <m>m<br>m<br>m<br>m<br></m>
  <n>n</n>
  <o>o</o>
</container>
```